# Doctrine Events: How can I track additions / removals to a ManyToMany collection?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an `Application` entity that has a ManyToMany relationship to the `SortList` entity. The owning side is `Application`. There's a simple join table that creates the mapping for this relationship.

Here's how the `Application` entity looks with regards to managing the collection:

```
/**
 * Add sortLists
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\SortList $sortList
 * @return Application
 */
public function addSortList(SortList $sortList)
{
    $this->sortLists[] = $sortList;
    $sortList->addApplication($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove sortLists
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\SortList $sortList
 */
public function removeSortList(SortList $sortList)
{
    $this->sortLists->removeElement($sortList);
    $sortList->removeApplication($this);
}

/**
 * Get sortLists
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getSortLists()
{
    return $this->sortLists;
}
```

**I want to track when `SortLists` have been added or removed from an `Application`**.

I've already learned that I can't use `postUpdate` lifecycle event to track these changes collections.

Instead, it seems I should use [onFlush](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush) and then `$unitOfWork->getScheduledCollectionUpdates()` and `$unitOfWork->getScheduledCollectionDeletions()`.

For updates, I see I can use the "internal" method `getInsertDiff` to see which items in the collection were added and `getDeleteDiff` to see which items in the collection were removed.

But I have a couple concerns:

1. If all items in the collection were removed, there's no way to see which items were actually removed since `$unitOfWork->getScheduledCollectionDeletions()` doesn't have this information.
2. I'm using methods that are marked as "internal"; it seems like they could "disappear" or be refactored some point in the future without me knowing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this empty getDeleteDiff in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277337/5418514

The reason this is sometimes empty is an old but still existing problem. The solution at the moment is to fetch the data again yourself.

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $uow = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork();
    
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledCollectionDeletions() as $collection) {
        /**
         * "getDeleteDiff" is not reliable, collection->clear on PersistentCollection also clears the original snapshot
         * A reliable way to get removed items is: clone collection, fetch original data
         */
        $removedData = $collection->getDeleteDiff();
        if (!$removedData) {
            $clone = clone $collection;
            $clone->setOwner($collection->getOwner(), $collection->getMapping());
            // This gets the real data from the database into the clone
            $uow->loadCollection($clone);

            // The actual removed items!
            $removedData = $clone->toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the examples below cover everything you would need so you just need to implement which ever you want/need in your app.

- For tracking `persist` operations, you can use [prePersist and
  postPersist event listener on an entity](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/jbm8/prepersist-and-postpersist-event-listener-on-an-entity) or [prePersist and
  postPersist event subscriber on an entity](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/3isc/prepersist-and-postpersist-event-subscriber-on-an-entity) examples. PrePersist
  won't give you the ID cos it doesn't exist in DB yet whereas
  PostPersist will as shown in the example.
- For tracking `remove` operations, you can use [preRemove and
  postRemove event listener on an entity](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/2djr/preremove-and-postremove-event-listener-on-an-entity) example.
- For tracking `update` operations which is the tricky one, you can use
  [preUpdate event listener on an entity](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/z1p4/preupdate-event-listener-on-an-entity) example but pay attention
  how it is done.
- For `inserting`, `updating` and `removing` operations, you can use
  [onFlush event listener on an entity](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/oymp/onflush-event-listener-on-an-entity) example which covers
  UnitOfWork `getScheduledEntityInsertions`,
  `getScheduledEntityUpdates` and `getScheduledEntityDeletions`
  methods.

There are many other useful listener examples in [that website](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/home) so just use search feature for `listener` keyword. Once I did same thing as you wanted for M-N associations but cannot find the example. If I can I'll post it but not sure if I can!

Comment: This doesn't help - my problem is specifically with ManyToMany collections - where the record that's being created/deleted is not actually an entity but instead represented by a simple join table that Doctrine manages.

Comment: In general you'll run into some limitations in your app anyway if you go for m-n relationship and not have a middle entity. If you go for 1-n and n-1 then you would get rid of all the possible limitatins like in your current case. It's your call anyway. Just a suggestion from me.